# Passar ID para o Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Estou com o problema de quando eu clico no botão para Cadastrar, a Cidade não passa o ID. Fiz. O ID está sendo passado para a tela, mas na hora de passar para o controller não.

```
<div class="alinhado col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class=" alinhadoLabel">
            @Html.Label("Cidade", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="alinhadoEditor">
            <select class="form-control" id="City"><option value="0">Selecione</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este é o controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PeopleID,Name,Email,Password,Address,Number,Neighborhood,ZipCode,Photo,Type,Active,Validate,DateBirth,Register,CityID")] People people)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Peoples.Add(people);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(people);
    }
```

e aqui o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa setar o name do seu select para o mesmo nome da propriedade para que o bind ocorra. No caso, CityID no lugar de City

```
 <select class="form-control" id="CityID" name="CityID"><option value="0">Selecione</option></select>
```

Comment: Realmente estava faltando a propriedade Name mesmo, porém o CityID não funcionou, teve que ser o City apenas